# Force Windows 8.1 Task Manager to always show More Details

Tags: windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1, with each restart, when I launch the Task Manager the first time during a session, it defaults to the *Fewer Details* view like so:

[image: Windows 8.1 Task Manager in "Fewer Details" mode]

I can get to the More Details view by clicking the *More Details* arrow, resulting in this:

[image: Windows 8.1 Task Manager in "More Details" mode]

Is there anyway to cause Windows to always default to the *More Details* view?

Comment: I did this once and when I run now Taskmgr I always get all details.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Does it stay that way after a reboot though? Mine changes back after rebooting.

Comment: yes, it stays there.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Perhaps you could leave the window set to "less details" -> export the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager\Preferences` -> set Task Manager to "more details" -> reboot -> check if "more details" is still on -> export registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager\Preferences` again -> compare the differences... I've read that things like the "always on top" and interval values can be changed by changing the hex values. Careful, though, the values are BINARY.

Comment: @BigChris here are the files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8d9krai10j7hw3q/AACB6sIfwVZowr4sHOzKpWjba?dl=0. I exported them from a Windows 8.1

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Can someone post the exact value that is modified? It looks like my default install on Server 2012 doesn't have a preferences key under TaskManager

Comment: @magicandre1981 Never mind; I thought it was a key, not a value. I've found it and I think this will do what I need. Is it possible to give the bounty to someone that only made a comment? If not, can you post that as an answer so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: @EGr What should I post? My 2 files in an answer?

Comment: Your top comment where you mention the keys

Comment: @EGr that was "big chris" and not me.

Comment: @BigChris - if you post your first post (with the key names) as an answer, I will give you the bounty. That was the resolution to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Leave Task Manager set to "less details"
2. Export the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager\Preferences` and save it to, say, your Desktop
3. Set Task Manager to "more details"
4. Restart your computer (to simulate the settings being reverted)
5. Re-open Task Manager and check if "more details" is still on
6. Export registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\TaskManager\Preferences` again
7. Compare the differences of the registry keys (in the exported .reg files on your Desktop)

I've read that things like the "always on top" and refresh interval values can be changed by changing the hex values. Careful, though, the values are BINARY so decoding and working them out could be difficult...

Comment: Do you have any idea if the values that change and what they will change in to will always be the same?

Comment: @marijnr are you asking if there is a specific location in the binary data that identifies the specific change? I'm sorry, I've absolutely no idea... the file being binary may not have set locations because of such preferences as which columns and orders you set which, inevitably, will change the binary entry and its length.

Answer (score 0):

The display should default to the More Details view if in the
View menu one unchecks the "Group by type" option :

[image]

For further customization of the display, right-click on the area where column names are displayed (name, memory, etc.), then enable other options such as
"Process name" :

[image]

Comment: I clicked the "More Options" button when I first started Task Managed & it's stayed the same ever since & I shut my machine down every night.  Not sure why yours would keep changing back...  Will keep having a look online and see if there is anything on making this change permanent.
For more info on Task Manager, there are some helpful tips & tricks here: http://www.nextofwindows.com/10-windows-8-1-task-manager-features-you-may-not-know :)

Comment: @Trav have you been having any more problems with your Task Manager reverting back to the Simple mode recently?